# C# ASP.Net The type or namespace name 'iAnywhere' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, namespaces, sybase

Morning all,

I know that this sounds like a simple referencing problem from the title this is becoming a nightmare!

I have a code class that uses the "iAnywhere.Data.AsaClient.dll". This Dll is referenced in the project and in the code class I have added this dll in the Using section.

Everything seems fine at build with no errors at all but when I go to run the application it comes up with the following Compilation Error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'iAnywhere' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The line that the Error points to this line in the class:

```
using iAnywhere.Data.AsaClient;
```

I have set the dll to copy local and it makes no difference, the Dll is installed on my PC so is in the GAC, I use this Dll with many other C# projects and have no problems.

I have scoured Google looking for an answer and haven't found anything that points me to an answer to my problem.

Any help would be brilliant!

Comment: This seems to have been resolved by moving the class file from the App_Code folder into the main file area of the project although I now have a reference problem with my own class files! I will open a new question for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has all been going wrong because a colleague was attempting to add in additional functionality and was clearly very unsuccessful!

Upon reverting his changes it is now working perfectly.