# C# ASP.Net The type or namespace name 'Secure' does not exist in the namespace 'source_extranet'

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, reference, namespaces

Afternoon all,

I really need your help as this is a Nightmare!

I was earlier having a problem with referencing a 3rd Party Dll ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911737/c-asp-net-the-type-or-namespace-name-ianywhere-could-not-be-found)) but have overcome this problem and am now having a problem referencing my own classes!

Everything seems fine at build with no errors at all but when I go to run the application it comes up with the following Compilation Error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Secure' does not exist in the namespace 'source_extranet' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The line that the Error points to this line in the class:

```
source_extranet.Secure.BackendCustomData newdata =
new source_extranet.Secure.BackendCustomData();
```

This line of code points to a class in the same folder as the calling code class.

I have scoured Google looking for an answer and haven't found anything that points me to an answer to my problem.

Any help would be AMAZING!

Comment: Seems that the dll containing the namespace Secure is not on your BIN folder. How are you running your APP?

Comment: Where does the class code reside? In the App_Code folder?

Comment: Where do you *`go` to run the application*? Are you able to run the app with ctrl+f5?

Comment: Do you have any config files attached to the application?

Comment: @Claudio - The code class is in my application and is correctly built into a dll and placed into the Bin folder.
@alex - The code class is in a sub folder in the project folder. The calling code class is also in the same folder.
@KMan - I am running through Visual Studio 2008.
@Nix - There is a web.config file included in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has all been going wrong because a colleague was attempting to add in additional functionality and was clearly very unsuccessful!

Upon reverting his changes it is now working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your class Secure also uses the source_extranet namespace.  And if its a partial class make sure the partials also have the right namespace.

Comment: The class namespace is "source_extranet.Secure".